# Kofax Capture: can a batch be separated in documents containing a variable number of pages?

Tags: capture, kofax

I have a batch class that contains a batch field named `pageCount`.

The idea is that the user set this variable when creating the batch, and the pages will be separated in documents containing `pageCount` pages each.

I can't find a way to do it, so is it actually doable?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batch class being synchronized with a KTM project, simply activate the option to separate pages (Standard Separation) in your project's properties.

Now every new batch created with this class will allow you to set its number of pages per document in the creation box (the corresponding combobox was disabled before that).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could achieve this sort of functionality.  It depends a little on other parts of the project - standard KC or KTM etc.

Either way some customisation - workflow agent/custom panel/custom module will be required.

Something like a custom batch splitting module like [easyBatchSplitter](http://www.davidcrewe.com/easybatchsplitter.html) may help.